# inconsistency between different ways of appending to a slice

Tags: go, append

I came across this inconsistency in calling "append" using variadic form vs appending a single element. See: https://play.golang.org/p/rR0su5FxhMX

Two slices, initialized from same slice.

- Add an element to one of them.
- Add two elements to the other. Scenario 1: add those two elements by calling "append" twice. Scenario 2: add those two elements in a single call.

Result: In Scenario 1, appending to the second slice overrides the last element of the first slice. Scenario 2 leaves it intact.

If "append" changes the underlying structure (which should be the case), that explains Scenario 1. Why does it not work the same in Scenario 2? (or the other way around)

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go and read https://blog.golang.org/slices and https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro. Pro tip: Reading the  official documentation is well worth the time spent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common mistake that results from ignoring the fact that a slice is a view on an array. In other words, a slice does not own its elements. When you append to a slice that does not have sufficient capacity, the runtime allocates a larger array and copies data to the new array. Slices working with the old array sill point to the old array.

In your first case, you add elements one by one, and array copy occurs when you add "six". So both slices share the underlying array for "four" and "five".

In the second case, the two elements "five" and "six" are added using a single `append`, so a new array is allocated before these two are added.